# Reading alternative lines of multiple files and aggregating them into a single CSV

Tags: csv, batch-file, for-loop, export-to-csv

Here's what I'm trying to do:

1. Loop through all files in a directory
2. Loop through every other line, starting with the first (all odd-numbered lines), and get the number in the line.
3. Write the number and the next line to an output.txt file

The data looks like this:

```
>      234.01 Burgeron/ Tom                       Tom Burgeron
  Here is some information.
>      126.00 Waka/ Judy                   Judy Waka
  Here is some more information.
```

I'm trying to make it look like this:

```
"234.01","Here is some information."
"126.00","Here is some more information."
```

Here's the batch file I'm writing:

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
//Loop through all files in folder
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (*) do (
    CALL :GetNumber %%a
    echo "!num!",%%a
) >> FILEOUTPUT.txt

//Get number on the odd-numbered lines
:GetNumber
for /f "tokens=1 delims=>" %%a in (%1) do (
    set "num=%%a"
)
```

I'm having trouble getting every other line of the file and then reading the next line/writing it into the file. I've seen how to skip specific lines, but not how to skip every other. How do I then take the next line?

This batch file is a bit complicated for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: How are you skipping lines?  Your example tells me you are combining every two lines together.

Comment: Haha. That's one of the things I'm having problems with. I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You should probably start smaller.  The only two lines of code that actually work are the first two lines.  You are not even getting all the files in the folder correctly.

Comment: Where should I start? I'm pretty new to batch scripting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show one way to alternate processing the lines:

```
@ECHO off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
REM Loop through all files in folder
for %%a in (*) do for /f "delims=" %%b in (%%a) do (
  if defined num (
    echo "!num!","%%b"
    set "num="
  ) else (
    for /f "tokens=1 delims=> " %%c in ("%%b") do set num=%%c
  )
)
```

Note the above script can't reside in the folder containing the data files, or it will be processed as data.

Comment: Good point. I wasn't sure about that. I'm guessing I need to replace the (*) with a folder path? I'm researching it now but not sure. Is there an easy way to make it so it's the folder that I drag onto the bat file?

Comment: For now, I'll just delete the part that gets pulled in from the bat file. The data is all there though. Thank you!